# Explaining what it means for a polynomial to be irreducible over F

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let F be a field and let F[x] be the ring of polynomials in one indeterminate
x with coefficients in F. Explain what it means for a polynomial g(x) in F[x] to be irreducible over
F.

I am thinking like this (very important to get it right):

It means that the polynomial of degree n>=1 with coefficients in a Field F is said to be irreducible over F if it cannot be written as a product of two non-constant polynomials over F of degree less than n.

Enough to get it correct? Or maybe add a line about them all being primes?

Comment: "It cannot be written as a product of two non-constant polynomials over $F$" is enough.

Comment: You were doing very well, up to that last sentence :-(

Comment: What sentence is that? about primes?

Comment: A polynomial in $\Bbb F[x]$ is reducible over $\Bbb F$ when it can be factored using only polynomials of lesser degree. A non-constant polynomial in $\Bbb F[x]$ is irreducible when it is not reducible.

Comment: just to nitpick: replace "non constant" by "of degree greater than or equal to 1". depending on $F$, it may be the case that some polynomials over $F$ have degree greater than zero but induce constant polynomial functions on $F$

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to state that it has a factorization into primes with at least two factors, but it's equivalent for polynomial rings.

In a general ring, an element $r$ is *irreducible* if, whenever it is written as $r=ab$, exactly one of $a$ and $b$ is invertible. Writing $r\mid a$ if there exists $b$ such that $r=ab$, another way to say this is that $r$ is irreducible if, whenver $a\mid r$, $r\mid a$.

This is different to prime, which is: $r$ is *prime* if $r$ is not zero of invertible and, whenever $r\mid ab$, $r\mid a$ or $r\mid b$.

In an integral domain (with unity) $R$, every prime is irreducible, but not every irreducible need be prime. To see that every prime is irreducible, suppose that $r$ is prime and $r=ab$. Since $r=ab$, certainly $r\mid ab$. Thus $r\mid a$ or $r\mid b$, without loss of generality $r\mid a$. Thus $a=rs$ for some $s$, and thus
$$ r=ab=rsb.$$
Since $R$ is an integral domain and $r(1-sb)=0$, we see that $sb=1$. In particular, $b$ is invertible, so that $r$ is irreducible.

Rings where every irreducible is prime are *unique factorization domains*, or UFDs.  This is equivalent to the statement that every element $r\in R$ has a factorization into irreducibles, **and**, the irreducibles that appear in this factorization are unique up to reordering and multiplying by invertible elements.

Polynomial rings (in potentially many variables) over fields are examples of UFDs, so for polynomial rings there are multiple potential definitions of irreducible.

Comment: Well, the definition is the first thing you wrote. It would be more precise to say that there are many equivalent conditions.

Comment: I see your point, and that's true in a general ring. But the definition of irreducible *for a polynomial* assumes a priori that we are inside a polynomial ring. I personally would still use the 'real' definition, but if we are doing that then essentially everyone gives an incorrect definition of a prime number, because they define an irreducible number...

Comment: Touche. With prime numbers, there is a difference between "prime number" and "prime element of $\mathbf Z$". But the same can be argued for polynomials, I guess. Although, in my defence, when talking about irreducible polynomials, you don't necessarily mean irreducible over a field.

Comment: @tomasz I would always define irreducible polynomial in a lecture course the 'correct' way, not least because of the similarity with prime numbers. I can definitely see your point that the right definition in a special case should be one that generalizes to a broader collection of examples. So I will label this as 'bug; will not fix', rather than 'feature'.